# Angular Route Default Auxiliary Routes

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

When I read about Angular Router's auxiliary routing it is discussed as being an "independent" set of routes. However, what I'm trying to create "dependent" routes. For example:

```
/home -> HomeComponent, WelcomeComponent
/about -> AboutComponent, SearchComponent
/products -> ProductsComponent, ProductListComponent
/pricing -> PricingComponent, WelcomeComponent
```

I want to be able to just specify the main (page) route like the following code and based on my example above load these two components (AboutComponent, SearchComponent).

```
<a routerLink="/about">About</a>
```

I can get the two components to load when I use the following:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { primary: ['about'], sidebar: ['search'] } }]">
    Products List
</a>
```

However, I really don't want the link to know about the auxiliary route. I want it supplied automatically. Is this possible with the right configuration? Or will this require me to extend the RouteModule to do this?

*Edit:*

Another requirement I have to is to keep the  peer to each other. The layout of the site is such that the second component is not within the main component.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding my answer here under the section entitled "Componentless Routes": https://vsavkin.tumblr.com/post/146722301646/angular-router-empty-paths-componentless-routes

Here is the code example in that link:

```
[
  {
    path: 'team/:id',
    component: TeamParentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: TeamListComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: TeamDetailsComponent,
        outlet: 'details'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options based on my knowledge.

Option 1 : create a main route with a children component

app.routing.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
   path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,
   children: [{ path: '', component: WelcomeComponent }],
  },
  {
   path: 'about', component: AboutComponent,
   children: [{ path: '', component: SearchComponent }],
  },
  {
   path: 'products ', component: ProductsComponent,
   children: [{ path: '', component: ProductListComponent }],
  },
  {
   path: 'pricing  ', component: PricingComponent,
   children: [{ path: '', component: WelcomeComponent }],
  }
}];
```

You have your main component e.g. AboutComponent.
And in it, you have to put a `<router-outlet>` to place your children component.

about.component.html

```html
<!-- code of your component -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<!-- code of your component -->
```

Option 2 :

you put your children component directly in your parent component but you cannot call that a routing at that point.

about.component.html

```html
<!-- code of your component -->
<app-search-component></app-search-component>
<!-- code of your component -->
```

Comment: Good answer. Though, your answer reminds me what I forgot to say in my original question. I'm trying to use aux routes since I have a large site layout and want these different components to show up at very different locations with. I want to keep these router-outlets peer to each other instead of encapsulating them.